# Why is this naive sieve implementation so slow

Tags: f#, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Here's my code

```
let primes =
    let rec primesRec remain = 
        let prime = Seq.head remain
        seq { yield Seq.head remain; yield! primesRec (Seq.filter (fun n -> n % prime <> 0) remain)  }
    primesRec (Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 2))
```

First of all, I know that this isn't as efficient as the sieve should be, but I think it should still be much faster than it is.

```
Seq.take 100 primes |> List.ofSeq
```

already takes a noticable amount of time (<1s), and it completely freezes for 1000 (as in, I don't want to wait anymore).

So, as far as I can tell, this sequence is constructed by taking the first element of the remaining ones and then recursing to generate the other ones but filtering the rest.
Am I wrong in thinking that this is quadratic in complexity? It just goes through all the existing primes to each new prime it has to generate.

I know that since I want the 1000th prime, it's actually quadratic in the size of that prime, which is around 8000, but that should still be around 100 000 000 iterations. Shouldn't that execute in under a second?

Comment: you might enjoy this: [the genuine sieve](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) - also have a look at this [site](http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_(Haskell)) - it's all explained there

Comment: Whatever the code does 100M iterations is quite a lot to squeeze into a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not memoizing the `remain` seq so for every iteration, it is calculating all the primes up to `prime` again.

You theory about there being 100M iterations may be correct, but remember it's not just doing a little modulo operation: it's creating sequences and iterators and allocating memory and pushing stuff onto the stack and so on.

I made this performant by caching the `remain` seq as follows. But you could also solve it by using `List` instead of `seq`.

```
let primes =
    let rec primesRec remain = 
        let prime = Seq.head remain
        seq { yield Seq.head remain; yield! primesRec (Seq.filter (fun n -> n % prime <> 0) (Seq.cache remain))  }
    primesRec (Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 2))
```

Comment: can you give some code to solve this with lists in F#? (this is a bit mean - the one think `seq`s have is that they are lazy .. you have a problem with lists here ...)